# Typescript - function get skipped

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor

The below function gets skipped in debugging in all scenarios.
I really can't tell the reason.
nothing is thrown out of the catch block.
On debugging, I immediately reach the last line after the catch block.
Thanks for the help.

```
  public async Function(licence:string,stepDescription) {
    try{
        let count:number = await this.doctorsLicenceNumbers.count();
        let checked:boolean = false;
        let doctorRefernceFromWeb;
        for(let i=0; i < count; i++) {
            doctorRefernceFromWeb = await this.doctorsLicenceNumbers.get(i).getText(); 
            if (doctorRefernceFromWeb == licence) {
                checked=true;
                await this.doctorsReferncesCheckBoxes3.get(i).click();
            }
        };
        }
            
    }catch(e){
        console.log("function failed error is: " +e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean nothing is thrown out of the catch?, you mean console.log isn't executed? and which function is skipped?

Comment: checkDoctorReferenceByLicence this function is skipped .if there is an error with this function then the catch block will be executed

Comment: where are you invoking `checkDoctorReferenceByLicence` ?

Comment: add a `console.log('xxx')` ahead `try` to confirm it indeed run into the function, remove all codes in `try {}` block, only leave a `console.log('yyy')` to see the issue comes from the codes in `try {}` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what solved this issue was casting the objects from elementArrayFinder to an array of elementFinder.
Thanks all.